# split a single cell in excel containing multi-line data:

Tags: excel, parsing

I want to split a single cell in excel containing the following multi-line data:

> DC(I_T: 0; FS: 100; TL: 0; ZS: 100)
>   FO(MO: Temp; PI: E_A_MT; Fr: 0; OT: 20)
>   Lam1(L_S: LFS1 (UN); Fr: 0; OT: 0.1)
>   Lam2(L_S: LFS1 (UN); Fr: 0; OT: 0.9)

I have tried to parse the entire cell using

`=IF(ISERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND(")",A1)-1)),A1,LEFT(A1,FIND(")",A1)-1))`

AND

`=IF(ISERROR(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(")",A1))),"",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(")",A1)))`

But with these formulas, I could only get

> DC(I_T: 0; FS: 100; TL: 0; ZS: 100

and

> FO(MO: Temp; PI: E_A_MT; Fr: 0; OT: 20)
>   Lam1(L_S: LFS1 (UN); Fr: 0; OT: 0.1)
>   Lam2(L_S: LFS1 (UN); Fr: 0; OT: 0.9)

in two different columns (A2 and B2 respectively).

Further the cell containing

> FO(MO: Temp; PI: E_A_MT; Fr: 0; OT: 20)
>   Lam1(L_S: LFS1 (UN); Fr: 0; OT: 0.1)
>   Lam2(L_S: LFS1 (UN); Fr: 0; OT: 0.9)

was parsed using `=IF(ISERROR(LEFT(B2,FIND(")",B2)-1)),B2,LEFT(B2,FIND(")",B2)-1))` which ended with

> FO(MO: Temp; PI: E_A_MT; Fr: 0; OT: 20

in one cell.

Expected result is:
[image: An 8-column by 5-row grid. The top row is 4 2-wide merged cells]

Comment: All that information is just in one cell? Including next line characters? Or are these actually 4 cells?

Comment: All the information is just in one cell. Including the next line characters too

Comment: A VBA solution would be easiest, especially since you seem to want Merged Cells (or Center_Across_Selection formatting) in your results.